# Can I have a grok expression to have only internal id and hostname?

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

Can you write a grok expression for the following requirement:

We have 3 types of events, as shown below:

```
08D7119FBFEC19B7;250 2.6.0 <DM6PR09MB3369DAB34BC8812C1CF1E16181C00@DM6PR09MB3369.namprd09.prod.outlook.com> [InternalId=669077,Hostname=Abcd] Queued mail for delivery
08D7119FBFEC19B7;250 2.6.0 <DM6PR09MB3369DAB34BC8812C1CF1E16181C00@DM6PR09MB3369.namprd09.prod.outlook.com> [InternalId=669077] Queued mail for delivery
08D7119FBFEC19B7;250 2.6.0 <DM6PR09MB3369DAB34BC8812C1CF1E16181C00@DM6PR09MB3369.namprd09.prod.outlook.com> [Hostname=Abcd] Queued mail for delivery
```

For the above events, write a single grok expression which satisfies the following cases:

1. Grok should fetch `InternalId` and `Hostname` values if both are present
2. Grok should fetch the `InternalId` value if only `InternalId` is present
3. Grok should fetch the `Hostname` value if only `Hostname` is present

Comment: What have you tried so far? What worked and didn't work?

Comment: ((.*\[InternalId=%{NUMBER:InternalId}.*Hostname=%{USERNAME:Hostname}\])|(.\[InternalId=%{NUMBER:InternalId}.)|(.\[Hostname=%{USERNAME:Hostname}.))                                    This is the grok expression for them . I have worked on it.

Answer (score 1):

((.*[InternalId=%{NUMBER:InternalId}.*Hostname=%{USERNAME:Hostname}])|(.[InternalId=%{NUMBER:InternalId}.)|(.[Hostname=%{USERNAME:Hostname}.))

This is the grok expression which gives the exact output.